# How to test if function is called after clicking attachFiles button in Body component using React Testing Library in composite components?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-testing-library, react-test-renderer, react-testing

I am new to react and currently I am trying to write unit test cases for my component but facing several issues,

`Failed: "Test failed because it logged error to the console: Warning: React.createElement: type is invalid -- expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: %s.%s%s [undefined, You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.`

All my imports are proper.

In my component I am trying to return a renderer component which is having 3 integrated components, and feature is working I am only unable to test.

Code reference:
My container implementation:

```
import * as React from "react";

export interface IMyTaskProps
  extends Pick<
    IHeaderFooterProps,
    "appDef" | "onClose"
  > {
  convId: string;
  saveTabError?: string;
  createSomething: (
    
    isReq?: boolean,
    values?: IMyFileValues
  ) => void;
}

export const MyTaskContainer: React.FunctionComponent<
  IMyTaskProps
> = props => {
  const { appDef, onClose, createSomething } = props;;

  const attachFiles = (_files: FileInput[]): void => {
    onSaveClickCreate(abc, _files); //abc is some values we can ignore for now
  };

  const closeFunction = (): void => {
    onClose(false);
  };

  const onSaveClickCreate = React.useCallback(
    (abc, ...args) => {
      const [{id, fileName }] = args[0];
     
      const objectId = id.toString();
  

      createSomething(
        {
          // sending somevalues from args,
        },
        true,
        abc
        {
        
          objectId,
         
        }
      );
    },
    [createSomething]
  );

  const [showAboutDialog, setShowAboutDialog] = React.useState(false);
  const onAboutDialogOpenCallback = () => {
    setShowAboutDialog(true);
  };
  const onAboutDialogCloseCallback = () => {
    setShowAboutDialog(false);
  };
  const onCloseClicked = () => {
    onClose(false);
  };

  const component1 = (
    <Header
      name={"name"}
      onClose={onCloseClicked}
      onAboutDialogOpen={onAboutDialogOpenCallback}
    />
  );

  const component2 = (
    <Body
      attachFiles={attachFiles}
      closeFilesSuperPicker={closeFunction}
    />
  );

  const about = showAboutDialog && (
    <AboutRenderer
      onClose={onAboutDialogCloseCallback}
    />
  );

  return (
    <MyRenderer 
      header={component1}
      body={component2}
      about={about}
    />
  );
};
```

My renderer file:

```
import * as React from "react";


export interface IMyRendererProps {
  header: JSX.Element;
  body: JSX.Element;
  about: ReactNode;
}

export const MyRenderer = (
  props: IMyRendererProps
) => {

  const { header, body, about } = props;

  return (
    <>
      {header}
      {body}
      {about}
    </>
  );
};
```

and below is the test,

```
import * as React from "react";.
import { render, screen } from "@testing-library/react";

jest.mock("./path", () => {
  const originalModule = jest.requireActual(
    "./path"
  );
  return {
    ...originalModule,
    MyRenderer: jest.fn(
      ({ children, ...props }) => <div {...props}>{children}</div>
    ),
  };
});


const defaultProps: IMyTaskProps = {
  actionType: ActionTypes.Create,
  appDef: { name: "mockName", ImageUrl: "example" } as IDef,
  Id: "Id",
  onClose: jest.fn(),
  createSomething: jest.fn(),
};

describe("Testing MyTaskContainer", () => {

  afterEach(() => {
    jest.clearAllMocks();
  });

  test("should render the component", () => {
    console.log("Test case reached here");
    //  expect.assertions(1);

    render(<MyTaskContainer {...defaultProps} />);

    console.log(screen.debug());

  });
```

Not sure why, I have mocked my renderer and giving values using default props.
Can someone help me to understand how can I write the test cases in integrated components and how can I test if 'createSomething' is called when 'attachFiles' button is clicked?

I wanted to test rendering and test if `createSomething` is called after we click on `attachFiles`